# camel proxied web service returns an empty soap envelope

Tags: java, cxf, apache-camel

I'm using Camel to proxy a webservice (I need to modify the soap header first). I'm using the CXF_MESSAGE dataformat as that allows me to easily change the soap header. 
Sending a soap message using soapui works fine, and I can see it arrives at the real webservice, however, **the response is always an empty soap envelope**? When I switch to the MESSAGE dataformat the response is correct (but then I can't change the SOAP headers).

What am I doing wrong? Why does the dataformat change the in/out behaviour?

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="broker">
      ...
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>

<camelContext id="camelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <endpoint id="realWS" uri="http://localhost:8080/service?throwExceptionOnFailure=true" />

    <route>
        <from uri="cxf:bean:broker?dataFormat=CXF_MESSAGE" />
        <to ref="realWS" />
    </route>        
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no such `CXF_MESSAGE` data format at all. There are `POJO` (which is default), `PAYLOAD` and `MESSAGE`. With the `MESSAGE` data format you won't be able to process any `SOAP` - this mode applies to no `SOAP` processing.

In order to process `SOAP` headers you need to specify the `PAYLOAD` data format. Then you would be able to process `SOAP` headers. Check [here](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html#CXF-HowtogetandsetSOAPheadersinPAYLOADmode) how to do this. **Note:** In this link the routes are done via Java code. In order to do this via Spring you'll have to create your own [Processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) and then from URI forward your message to your custom processor, modify headers and send it back to the real endpoint.

**See also:**

- [Proxying with PAYLOAD Format](http://fusesource.com/docs/esbent/7.1/camel_cxf/Proxying-Payload.html)
- [Apache Camel CXF Component](http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html)

Comment: CXF_MESSAGE was added in Camel 2.8.2. (mentioned in your second link) Switching to PAYLOAD gives me a org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfPayload cannot be cast to javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage when I make my request. Or does the 'to' endpoint also need to be a CXF bean?

Comment: Yes. It also needs to be a camel cxf bean. First you have to create a class and implement the Processor interface. Then create a bean of it in your spring and forward it (from) the endpoint `to` your camel bean: `<camel:bean ref="yourCustomProcessor"/>` then `to` real ws.

Comment: Oops forgot to remove my processor, that threw the classcast. When I remove the processor and use PAYLOAD, I always get a HTTP operation failed invoking http://localhost:8088/mockBinding with statusCode: 500 as response. (I use SoapMock to test my setup, hence the 'mockBinding'.

Comment: Both endpoints are camel cxf beans now, using dataformat PAYLOAD. The request still arrives correctly, the response is now a soap fault with message "couldn't parse stream.". (the soap header transformation is no problem, removed that for now, just want a basic request/response exchange to work)

Comment: Solved, SoapUI used gzip to compress the response: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/CXF-problem-when-receiving-web-service-response-td4994825.html. Still would like to get it working with CXF_MESSAGE though, but at least I now have 1 working option.

Comment: Apparently the gzip option butched the CXF_MESSAGE way too but with a different error. So actually, the solution is: using cxf beans on both sides of the route ánd disabling gzip in the soapui mock service.